# Volley newRequestQueue 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

```
public final fun sendDeviceToken() {

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
            if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                return@addOnCompleteListener
            }
            val token = it.result //this is the token retrieved

            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
            val url = "https://example.com"

            val requestBody = "token=$token"
            val stringReq : StringRequest =
                object : StringRequest(Method.POST, url,
                    Response.Listener { response ->
                        // response
                        var strResp = response.toString()
                        Log.d("API", strResp)
                    },
                    Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                        Log.d("API", "error => $error")
                    }
                ){
                    override fun getBody(): ByteArray {
                        return requestBody.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset())
                    }
                }
            queue.add(stringReq)

        }

    }
```

I am newbie in Kotlin and trying to send devicetoken to server
When I call MainActivity().sendDeviceToken() function I get `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`

How can I pass context to newRequestQueue?

Check the whole code here https://codefile.io/f/uhfe84zzxexSDBp1GBSG

Answer (score 0):

Activities only have a `Context` when the system has created them, and they've reached the `CREATED` state of their lifecycle (i.e. `onCreate` has been called). So you can only use an `Activity` as a `Context` (like in your `newRequestQueue(this)` call) once it's in that `CREATED` state.

It's the system handling an Activity's creation and setup and callbacks that makes it work as an Activity component. Without that, it's just a plain object - and that's all you get if you construct one yourself, with `MainActivity()`. Since the usefulness of an Activity is how it interacts with the system, there's basically no reason to ever construct one yourself, because it won't really "work".

If you want to use that method outside of an Activity, add a `Context` parameter and use that in your `newRequestQueue` call.

```
public final fun sendDeviceToken(context: Context) {
    ...
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
```

Then call it from somewhere you *do* have access to a `Context`. And ideally, if you're really not calling this from an `Activity` or `Fragment`, it shouldn't be inside an `Activity` class at all - you shouldn't need to construct one specially to call this method, basically.

Comment: can you please check the code here https://codefile.io/f/uhfe84zzxexSDBp1GBSG I was not able to make it work

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz at a guess now you're getting it from `MainActivity().sendDeviceToken("3434", MainActivity().applicationContext)` because a newly constructed `Activity` doesn't have access to a `Context` for the reasons I mentioned. Your error log will tell you exactly which line is causing the problem (and what calls lead up to it)

Comment: How can I call sendDeviceToken from other class then?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz you'll need to do it from somewhere you have access to a Context. If you can't do this from inside an Activity or Service created by the system (which will attach a context as part of the lifecycle as explained) you might need to do it by e.g. creating your own `Application` subclass, which has access to `applicationContext` in `onCreate` and doing your setup there. If you're using dependency injection like Hilt, that has ways of providing a context to your components. I can't tell you exactly what you need to do, but that's what you need to look into!